# Spring Security UI and grails 2.0

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spring-security, grails-2.0

I am not able to use grails security UI(0.1.2) with Grails 2.0.
I have googled the possible causes for following error and also have tried suggested fixes but they don't seem to be working.
I have already tried, overriding the UIs, I also have tried Grails 2.0-m2 version.

```
| Error 2012-01-02 17:17:12,659 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] ERROR [/webdemo].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/webdemo] threw exception
Message: It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutResources tag. After rendering your page the following have not been rendered: [head]
   Line | Method
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     ''
^   619 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Following is my main.gsp (some code/comments are removed for brevity)

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon.png')}">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon-retina.png')}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'mobile.css')}" type="text/css">
        <g:layoutHead/>
        <r:layoutResources />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="grailsLogo" role="banner"><a href="http://grails.org"><img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'grails_logo.png')}" alt="Grails"/></a></div>
        <g:layoutBody/>
        <div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>
        <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;"><g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/></div>
        <g:javascript library="application"/>
        <r:layoutResources />
    </body>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to remove any g:javascript calls (i.e. the `<g:javascript library="application"/>`) and load it via the resources infrastructure instead.

I am having the exact same problem here (with Grails 2.0.1) and this seems to resolve it.

If that solution does work for you too, you might want to consider filing a bug report - as this is at least a very confusing error message.

Comment: Which g:javascipt calls did you remove - the ones in he springSecurityUI plugin reqister and auth gsps? (By doing s2ui-override, I assume?) Could you share the resulting resources module?

Comment: In my situation, I had overridden register; I removed the g:javascript in the register.gsp layout (even though they were commented out), and the problem went away.

Answer (score 9):

Add `<r:layoutResources />` tag inside `<head>` and right before `</body>`.

This is needed by the [Grails Resources Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) and further documentation for the tag can be found here http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/ref/Tags/layoutResources.html

Comment: Please check my edit, I have added my main.gsp and I already have those tags in it. Thanks for a reply though

Answer (score 0):

**I was having getting the same message** *`It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutResources tag.`* **with following code**

```
    <g:javascript library='application' />
    <g:layoutHead/>
    <r:layoutResources />
```

**Fixed when moved** `<g:javascript/>` **call between** `layoutHead` **and** `layoutResources`

```
    <g:layoutHead/>
          <g:javascript library='application' />
    <r:layoutResources />
```